# Able to view JSON in console but don't know how to display in view - React-Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, axios

I am still learning React-Redux. I understand how to retrieve simple JSON arrays. However, I am not sure how to call a nested object. I am trying to grab the title and am viewing this in the console:

- Object

  - data : Object

    - data : Object

      - data : Object

        - after : "t3_5t0hy2" before : null children : Array[25]

          - 0 : Object

            - data : Object

              - title : "The Google Analytics Setup I Use on Every Site I Build (by Philip Walton)"

dataAction.js

```
import axios from 'axios';


export function fetchData(){
  return function(dispatch){
    axios.get("https://www.reddit.com/r/webdev/top/.json")
    .then((response) => {
      dispatch({ type: "FETCH_DATA_FULFILLED", payload: response.data})
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      dispatch({type: "FETCH_DATA_REJECTED", payload: err})
    })
  }
}

export function addData(id, text){
  return {
    type: 'ADD_DATA',
    payload:{
      id,
      title,
    },
  }
}

export function updateData(id, text){
  return {
    type: 'UPDATE_DATA',
    payload: {
      id,
      title,
    },
  }
}

export function deleteData(id){
  return {
    type: 'DELETE_DATA',
    payload: id
  }
}
```

Layout.js (component)

```
import React from "react"
import { connect } from "react-redux"

import { fetchUser } from "../actions/userActions"
import { fetchPartner } from "../actions/projectActions"
import { fetchData } from "../actions/dataActions"

@connect((store) => {
  return {
    user: store.user.user,
    userFetched: store.user.fetched,
    partner: store.partner.partner,
    partnerFetched: store.partner.fetched,
    data: store.data.data
  };
})
export default class Layout extends React.Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.dispatch(fetchUser())
    this.props.dispatch(fetchPartner())
    this.props.dispatch(fetchData())
  }


  render() {
    const { user, partner, data } = this.props;



    //const mappedData = data.map(data => <li>{data.title}</li>)

    return <div>
      <h1>{user.name}{user.age}</h1>
      <h1>{partner.title}</h1>
      <ul>{data.title}</ul>
    </div>
  }
}
```

Reducer.js

```
export default function reducer(state={
    data: {
      data: {}
    },
    fetching: false,
    fetched: false,
    error: null,
  }, action) {

    switch(action.type){
      case "FETCH_DATA":{
        return {...state, fetching:true}
      }
      case "FETCH_DATA_REJECTED":{
        return {...state, fetching: false, error: action.payload}
      }
      case "FETCH_DATA_FULFILLED":{
        return {...state, fetching: false, fetched: true, data: action.payload}
      }
      case "ADD_DATA":{
        return {...state, data: [...state.data, action.payload]}
      }
      case "UPDATE_DATA":{
        const { id, title } = action.payload
        const newData = [...state.data]
        const dataToUpdate = newData.findIndex(data => data.id === id)
        newData[dataToUpdate] = action.payload;

        return {...state, data: newData}
      }
      case "DELETE_DATA":{
        return {...state, data: state.data.filter(data => data.id !== action.payload)}
      }
    }
    return state
  }
```

When this issue is solved, the next step would be to iterate through the object, which I'm also not sure how to achieve.

Comment: where are your reducers?

Comment: added the reducer

Answer (score 0):

As you are sending payload: response.data You can go further in the object structure and send the actual data in payload.

Once you send the payload you would need a reducer which will change the state. Follow this tutorial on how to create reducer. 
http://blog.scottlogic.com/2016/05/19/redux-reducer-arrays.html

Then once the state is updated, you will have the code reading the values from state. Once the state change the React will automatically update or render and you can write your logic.

Comment: I have added my reducer

Comment: You will have to use createStore and you can use this tutorial for better understanding of redux https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-the-single-immutable-state-tree